# recover windows drive data after linux installation changes drive to ext4

Tags: linux, windows

I had windows installed in system and have 4 drives in which C:/ is windows and other drives have my data.
then I install linux in my C:/ drive
but at installation time it shows only two drives,
one had equal size which had C:/ drive so I installed linux in that drive.
Other had equal size of rest of drives which i did not touch but linux change its file system to ext4.
After installing linux I did not get my other drives.
in gParted it show that other drive have partition /dev/sda4 but not mounted and have 150GB used out of 183 GB. that's mean data of my other drive are in that partition.

Please help me to recover my data.
thanks in advance.

Comment: What linux distribution have u installed?  As you say your other hard drive partition is present, have you tried to mount it?

Comment: Linux version 3.2.0-4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.2.57-3+deb7u2

Comment: And if you open files (the equivalent to windows explorer), the hard drive you want to access is not present? If it is and you simply click it, it automatically gets mounted.

Comment: i have installed linux in C: so i can not access windows any more.

Comment: when i try to mount it gives error
The daemon is bieng inhibited

Comment: Ok, that's a progress. But you have to make some research before coming here and asking a question. The error you described has already been discussed and solved in several forums, Q/A sites. Google it and if none of the proposed solution works come here and ask again. For example start from [here](http://superuser.com/questions/461730/bypass-daemon-is-inhibited).

Comment: thanks for quick response 
i did killall udisk and mount drive but it open a drive structure like root. it mounted to /media/Sol which has same directory structure like root.

Comment: And what is the problem with that? Can't you navigate and check for your files? What do you mean by "a structure like root" ? You are no more on Windows. Linux filesystem uses a tree structure. Everything is under / (which is the root directory)

Comment: means not all directories as linux root has. bin, boot, dev, etc, home,.. I think when i mount sda4 it mount to Sol user to it which contains these directory... there should be other drives data or their directory structure...

Comment: Yes Windows has not this type of filesystem (/root , /bin , /boot ....) so a drive that contains windows will not have the same filesystem structure. If it is mounted on /media/Sol , look in this folder for the files you had in the Windows hard drives. (P.S I m the same person as below, we don't need to talk in 2 places :) ).

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from Debian official site :

> On a GNU/Linux system there's no necessary correspondence between directories and physical 
>   devices, as there is in Windows where each drive has its own directory tree beginning with 
>   a letter (such as C:)

So , given that the other drive is present, judging by the output of gparted as you said, you simply have to mount the partition(s) on a folder of your desire.

Check the [Chapter 13](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-tutorial/ch-disks.html) of debian tutorial on how you ll be able to accomplish this.

P.S You do not need Windows for this proccess.

Comment: in /etc/fstab file
it shows sda1 and sda4...
so if i add sda4 in this file i can mount this drive..
but i think this drive contains three drives which was in windows...
so i have to mount sda4 only...
but i m not sure how will recover data from all three drives...

Comment: Okay, open a terminal give the "sudo fdisk -l" command and check the output. You are probably missing something.

Comment: in sudo fdisk -l 
there three devices
sda1 which is swamp
sda2 bootable linux
sda4 has system sfs
that's it.

Comment: Ok. Then either you have not actually partitioned the drive in Windows as u claimed (you may just have made some sub-directories), or you accidentally formated these partition. If that is the case then don't write anything in your hard drive, and look for a program like [photorec](http://www.google.fi/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEUQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.unixmen.com%2Frecover-deleted-files-in-linux-with-photorec%2F&ei=vOefU5HTLsnN0QX5soGABQ&usg=AFQjCNGM_aJyT8n4Tylc2MGi_XrbesYDCw&sig2=Jlj7mBrEelDiMDd5gnA3Jw&bvm=bv.68911936,d.d2k) in order to recover your files.

Comment: i tried photorec. it searched and recovered files from my other drives  which are in sda4. but it just fetch and save files not structurally. it actually proves that my data is there but there is two solutions first is i mount W2K Dynamic/SFS and second is format with windows and save data some where else the reformat with linux...

Comment: Ok hold on. If the files are on sda4 (and you can mount the sda4 partition as I recall), the files are inside the folder where sda4 is mounted only if you have not formated them. If you cannot see the files through this then you probably formatted this partition (which is very likely as you said that its type is ext4 - and this is not used by Windows). So if the last one is our case, installing windows will not have any difference. You won't be able neither to see the ext4 partition nor to recover your files (except if you use again a program like photorec).

Comment: @RavinderSinghRawat moreover, regarding recovery programms like photorec, most of them which are free, do not remake the folder structure and/or the original names of the recovered files.